# Node mysqljs. How to properly close connections

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm using mysqljs to access MySQL with javascript.

I would like to point out that this process seems to work fine if a single piece of data.
I am feeding into my code a large set of data, to be processed line by line as a batch.

I create my connection like this:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    //debug: ['ComQueryPacket'],
    host        : dataSource.host,
    user        : dataSource.user,
    password: dataSource.password,
    database: dataSource.database
});
```

I have three functions that make database queries.

The function containing the SELECT query is built like this:

```
dbSearch(data){
  var sql = "SELECT * from table where field =? and otherfield=?";
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(sql, [data[0], data[1], (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error){
          console.log(error);
          reject("Database connection error: " + error);
         } else {
          resolve(results);
         }  
    });
  });
}
```

The code executes in another function:

```
if (dataItem){
  dbSearch(dataItem)
    .then((row) => {
        processingfunction(row);
    });
```

If I leave out connection.end() the code hangs and the stream of data is held up at the first item being processed.

If I put connection.end() inside the function, i get this error:

Database connection error: Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.

I put connection.end() as the last line of the code, everything works fine

The problem though is for the update and insert functions:

```
updateRecord(data){
  var sql = "UPDATE table set field=? where id=?";
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(sql, [data[0], data[1], (error, results, fields) => {
     if (error){
      console.log(error);
      reject("Database connection error: " + error);
     } else {
      resolve(results);
     }
    });
  });
}

inputRecord(data){
  var sql = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES(?,?,?)";
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(sql, [data[0], data[1], data[2]], (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error){
        console.log(error);
        reject("Database connection error: " + error);
      } else {
        resolve(results);
      } 
    });
  });
}
```

With connection.end() in the function I get this error.

```
Database connection error: Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.
(node:40700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Database connection error: Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.
(node:40700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:40700) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Based on the documentation, I have no clarity on how to properly handle closing the connection so that the code can process properly.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Could use some mentorinng from someone experienced with using the connections to process chunks of data and how to properly handle closing the connections?

**NOTE:**
**A similar problem happens when I try connection pooling, so that was not a workable solution.**

Answer (score 0):

You using connection pool, you don't have to close the conn manually. There is a `.query()` convenient method. Since you're already using `.query()`, don't close it at the end of the function.

> This is a shortcut for the pool.getConnection() -> connection.query() -> connection.release() code flow.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});

pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question pool still has the same problem. The code hangs unless the connection is closed or the pool connection is destroyed. release() does not prevent it from hanging.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an implicit connection. Meaning, you are attempting to query the database without explicitly connecting first. This means that each time you run this line:

```
reject("Database connection error: " + error);
```

You can't be certain that it was a connection error. It may have been a query error. I believe it is always best to explicitly create/destroy your connections.

```
inputRecord(data){
    var sql = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.connect(function(err){
            if(err) reject("Database connection error: " + error);
            connection.query(sql, [data[0], data[1], data[2]], (error, results, fields) => {
                connection.end(); // Now you are certain a connection was made, and can be terminated
                if (error){
                    console.log(error);
                    reject("Database connection error: " + error);
                } else {
                    resolve(results);
                } 
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Because this is a pattern that will be used over and over, I would suggest moving it to it's own function:

```
executeQuery(query, params){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.connect(function(err){
            if(err) reject("Database connection error: " + error); // Connection error with certainty
            connection.query(query, params, (error, results, fields) => {
                connection.end(); // Now you are certain a connection was made, and can be terminated
                if (error){
                    console.log(error);
                    reject("Database query error: " + error);  // Query error
                } else {
                    resolve(results);
                } 
            });
        });
    });
}
```

And then simply call the function:

```
inputRecord(data){
    var sql = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    return executeQuery(sql,[data[0],data[1],data[2]]);
}

updateRecord(data){
    var sql = "UPDATE table set field=? where id=?";
    return executeQuery(sql,[data[0],data[1]]);
}

dbSearch(data){
    var sql = "SELECT * from table where field =? and otherfield=?";
    return executeQuery(sql,[data[0],data[1]]);
}
```

To use connection pooling, executeQuery would become:

```
executeQuery(query, params){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(query, params,function(err,res){ // shortcut for connect, query,end - no need to terminate the connection
            if(err) reject(err);
            else    resolve(res);
        });
    });
}
```

This should solve your problem, but if not, it should at least help narrow down the possibilities by breaking out the error conditions and bringing all query related code into the same function.

**Checking for connection first**

```
getConnection(){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       if(connection.state === 'connected') resolve(connection);
       else {
            connection.connect(function(err) => {
                if(err) reject ("Connection error: " + error);
                else resolve(connection);
            });
       }
    });
 }

 executeQuery(query, params){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getConnection().then(connection =>{
            connection.query(query, params, (error, results, fields) => {
                connection.end(); // Now you are certain a connection was made, and can be terminated
                if (error){
                    console.log(error);
                    reject("Database query error: " + error);  // Query error
                } else {
                    resolve(results);
                } 
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: But No. This is exactly the thing that causes the error I pointed out in my question.

(node:5864) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Database connection error: Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake.
(node:5864) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by r
se which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: Database connection error: Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake.

Comment: Are you connecting to the database elsewhere, prior to these calls? You can try checking the connection state in the executeQuery function. This would be done before trying to connect. if(connection.threadId) // don't try to connect.

Comment: No the first connection is the query function.
I've disabled update and insert just so I can find out what's going on with closing the connection.

Comment: I've update my answer to include a function to check the connection before trying to connect. I can understand your frustrations as it sounds like things should be working.

Comment: What's interesting is that the connection is fine. Everything goes wonky if I don't close the connection AND if I do close the connection.

Comment: Can you post the entire controlling function showing the flow from connection.createConnection()... to DBSearch to UpdateRecord or InsertRecord? The underlying issue is likely there.